# How to authenticate some URL and ignore anything else

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, authentication

I want to manage security policy like below. ( HTTP Basic Authorization)

1. Apply authentication following URLs.
   "/foo/**", "/bar/**"
2. Ignore anything else URLs. ( Even though requests have Authorization field in header)

I know permitall(). But permitall() is not suitable because it apply security policy when request has Authorization field in headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want ignore particular url then you need to implement this method.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/static/**");
    }
}
```

You can put your url in place of **/static/**** in which you want no authentication apply.

> Your example means that Spring (Web) Security is ignoring URL patterns
> that match the expression you have defined ("/static/**"). This URL is
> skipped by Spring Security, therefore not secured.

**Read the Spring Security reference for more details:**
[Click here for spring security details](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/)